# Port forward is working, but not able to access the port from other PODs in the same GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a stateful set for MQ, exposed two ports 1414 for TCP and 9443 for HTTPS and created service of type Loadbalancer.    1414 for TCP is working fine, able to telnet from other PODs in the same cluster using service name/cluster IP..also able to connect 1414 from outside GKE cluster.

But the problem is port 9443 is not accessible from other POD in the cluster (service name/cluster IP) or outside the cluster (external IP).     The telnet is working fine when exec to the POD and test locally..  telnet 127.0.01 9443

Is there any configuration missing for HTTPS service..

Note: Port forward is working fine and able to connect to the API.  kubectl port-forward svc/mq-qmdtest 9443:9443

Service Definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{.Values.name}}
  namespace: {{.Values.namespace}}
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels : 
    run: {{.Values.name}}
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: {{.Values.loadBalancerIP}}
  ports:
  - name: webui
    port: 9443
    protocol: TCP
  - name: mq
    port: 1414
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: {{.Values.name}}
```

Stateful Set – Container port configuration

```
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9443
      protocol: TCP
      name: webui
    - containerPort: 1414
      protocol: TCP
      name: mq
```

Comment: can you provide output of "kubectl get endpoints SVC_NAME" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The telnet is working fine when exec to the POD and test locally.. telnet 127.0.01 9443
>   ...
>    Port forward is working fine and able to connect to the API. kubectl port-forward svc/mq-qmdtest 9443:9443

Is almost certainly caused by the pod only listening on localhost; `port-forward` also engages with localhost, so the fact that you cannot reach it from other pods in the cluster but you can from itself and you can from port-forward means the service is only listening for *local* connections.

Without knowing more about the software I can't offer you a "open this file, change this value" type instructions, but be on the lookout for "bind host" or any "listen" configuration that would accept both a host and a port, and in that case set the "bind host" to `0.0.0.0` or the "listen" configuration to `0.0.0.0:9443`

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input.   There was a configuration in MQ software’s web config file, by default, the server listens for HTTP/HTTPS requests on localhost only.  That was causing the problem.  The issue is resolved by removing the localhost reference.