# A gRPC connection fails in minikube environment

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs, grpc, minikube, coredns

Locally, bare-metal, two separate 'services' successfully talk to each other trough a gRPC connection, a client and a 'backend'. Both are implemented as NestJS apps, using the gRPC transports.

When deployed in kubernetes(minikube) environment I get `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established` in the client. Backend listens on `localhost:50051` (port is exposed from k8 service), frontend attempts connection on `engine-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:50051`, where the first part up until the dot is the service name and I've `nslookup`'d it to make sure this is the full domain name.

I tried port-forwarding to the gRPC kubernetes service, this 'backend' part of the connection works fine and communication to/from it works. Thus the 'frontend' deployment/pods is the part to fail establishing a connection.

Minikube comes packaged with coreDNS. I've tried debugging it but without success. When the 'frontend' service attempts to connect, the logs from coreDNS are labeled with `NOERROR` which I've read means the service is found; still it remains unsuccessfull.

What else could be an issue? What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053059). The problem was that the backend was listening on `localhost:50051` which means local connections only; port-forwarding also counts as one so that's why it worked. Changing the 'listen on' property to `0.0.0.0:50051` on the backend part solved the issue;